# Помогите с хранение данных из запроса в PHP

Tags: php, post, request

я новичок в PHP,первый день как я его учу,понадобилось для проекта,но у меня появилась проблема как её решить я не знаю, мне надо получать данные с запроса(время и токен) и чтоб они добовлялись в масив который будет хранить эти данные но проблема в том что при отправке запроса постменом он возврашает только одно значение вместо добаляние каждым запросом нового элемента 
вот код:

```
$data = $_REQUEST['token'];

$stack = array();
array_push($stack, $data);

foreach ($stack as $token) {
 echo $token." <br/>";
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

скриншот там видно что даже после 10 запросов возврашаеться один элемент хотя поидее массив их должен был вернуть 10,сорри если туплю

Comment: т.е. вы отправляете 10 запросов, но не видите в массиве данных всех этих 10 запросов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сохранять промежуточный результат с помощью кук например. 
**Они хранятся на диске у пользователя** - не на сервере.

Вот пример.

```js
$CookieKey = "my_cookie_key";
$get = $_REQUEST['token'];

// получаем предыдущий массив с куки, если его не существует - создаем новый
(isset($_COOKIE[$CookieKey]) ? $heap = unserialize($_COOKIE[$CookieKey]) : $heap = array());
// тут понятно
array_push($heap, $get);
// сохраняем массив в куки
setcookie($CookieKey, serialize($heap));
// пробегаем в цикле
foreach($heap as $token) {
  echo $token.
  " <br/>";
}
```

Конечно не лучший вариант, тем не менее рабочий.
Если нужно хранить инфу на сервере, то нужно использовать БД или сохранять данные в файлы на сервере.

---

Есть конечно и другие варианты хранения. Php просто работает по принципу загрузился в память=отработал=освободил память ... Вообщем вам это уже сказали наверное. Хотя можно повешать скрипт чтобы не умирал, если это необходимо.

Comment: Код в примере нужно размещать до любых выводов в браузер... Аля "echo('...')" / "<html tag> html content </html tag>"/  .
Иначе, будет ошибка если не изменяет память.

Answer (score 1):

php так не работает. Вы отправили запрос. Скрипт отработал, и все несохранённые данные и всё остальное уничтожается. Так что вам нужно данные сохранить, чтобы при втором и последующих вызовах получить их. Иными словами, php каждый раз начинает работу "с чистого листа". Выполняемая программа не знает, что было до неё. Оно знает только то, что написано. Она выполняет только те инструкции, которые есть тут и сейчас.